# Jquery prepend based on own content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need something in jQuery but can't figure it out.

I got this html:

```
 <h2>My Name 1</h2>
 <h2>My Name 2</h2>
 // many more
```

In jQuery I want to get the content of this `h2' and need that for:

```
 <h2><a href="My Name 1">My Name 1</a></h2>
```

This is working:

```
 jQuery(".content h2").prepend("<a href=''>").append("</a>");
```

But the `href` has to be based on its content... How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't append a chunk of HTML element like the half of `a` tag. Browser fixes such an invalid HTML and won't render it.

Use [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) method:

```
$('.content h2').wrapInner('<a href="something"></a>');
```

If link `href` attribute somehow depends on actual `h2` content then you should use function as `wrapInner` arguments, see Rory McCrossan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28914324/949476). For example to set `href` to be the same as `h2` content it can be:

```
$('h2').wrapInner(function() {
    return '<a href="' + $(this).text() + '"></a>';
});
```

Comment: I am almost there... Using the `wrapInner` gives me the content twice... How to fix that?

Comment: Solved :) had to leave the content of `a` empty :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that what you have is working as you expect because you can only append whole elements. Your current code would end up with something like this:

```
<h2>
    <a href=''></a>
    My name 1
    <a></a>
</h2>
```

Given that you want to effectively wrap the text of the `h2` in an `a` element you can use `wrapInner()` with a handler function containing the logic to set the `href`. Try this:

```
jQuery(".content h2").wrapInner(function() {
    var href = 'foo.php'; // your logic here
    return '<a href="' + href + '"></a>';
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vo12m3m5/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
$(".content h2").each(function (n) {
var x =$('h2').eq(n).text();
var y = x.replace(/\s/g, '');
$(".content h2").eq(n).empty().append("<a href="+y+">"+x+"</a>");
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
 <h2>My Names 1</h2>
 <h2>My Names 2</h2>
 <h2>My Names 3</h2>
 <h2>My Names 4</h2>
 <h2>My Names 5</h2>
</div>
```

> `Blockquote`

Answer (score 0):

So, grab the content of H2 and then append A with href and text as the grabbed content.

```
var h2Text = $(".content h2").text();
$(".content h2").empty().append( $("<a/>", { href: h2Text, text: h2Text }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var href = 'test.html'; 
jQuery(".content h2").prepend("<a href='"+href+"'>").append("</a>");
});
```